# Failed to start Samba NMB Daemon and other errors

Tags: server, active-directory, samba4

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu active directory domain controller with Samba.  I installed Samba, and configured it using samba-tool.

During system boot, I get 3 errors:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Samba NMB Daemon
See 'systemctl status nmbd.service' for details
[FAILED] Failed to start Samba Winbind Daemon.
See 'systemctl status winbind.service' for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
See 'systemctl status smbd.service' for details.
```

When I run `samba -i`, I get an error that says `setproctitle not initialized`, and also `Failed to listen on 0.0.0.0:53 - NT_STATUS_ADDRESS_ALREADY_ASSOCIATED`

My smb.conf contains:

```
[global]
    dns forwarder = 127.0.0.53
    netbios name = EXAMPLESERV
    realm = EXAMPLE.LOCAL
    server role = active directory domain controller
    workgroup = EXAMPLE
[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/example.local/scripts
    read only = No
[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = No
```

This is currently in a virtual machine.
I spent a few hours trying to fix this.  Any suggestions on how I can get it working?

**Edit:**
The output of `systemctl status nmbd.service` is:

```
nmbd.service - Samba NMB Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nmbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-07-06 17:19:41 UTC; 23min ago
 Docs: man:nmbd(8)
       man:samba(7)
       man:smb.conf(5)
Process: 881 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nmbd --foreground --no-process-group $NMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 881 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 06 17:19:36 exampleserv systemd[1]: Starting Samba NMB Daemon...
Jul 06 17:19:40 exampleserv nmbd[881]: [2018/07/06 17:19:40.885641,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd.c:923(main)
Jul 06 17:19:40 exampleserv nmbd[881]:   server role = 'active directory domain controller' not compatible with running nmbd standalone.
Jul 06 17:19:40 exampleserv nmbd[881]:   You should start 'samba' instead, and it will control starting the internal nbt server
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv systemd[1]: nmbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv systemd[1]: nmbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba NMB Daemon.
```

The output of `systemctl status winbind.service` is:

```
winbind.service - Samba Winbind Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/winbind.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-07-06 17:19:41 UTC; 24min ago
 Docs: man:winbindd(8)
       man:samba(7)
       man:smb.conf(5)
Process: 1083 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/winbindd --foreground --no-process-group $WINBINDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 1083 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv systemd[1]: Starting Samba Winbind Daemon...
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv systemd[1]: winbind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv systemd[1]: winbind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba Winbind Daemon.
```

The output of `systemctl status smbd.service` is:

```
smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/smbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-07-06 17:19:41 UTC; 25min ago
 Docs: man:smbd(8)
       man:samba(7)
       man:smb.conf(5)
Process: 1108 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group $SMBDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 1108 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv systemd[1]: Starting Samba SMB Daemon...
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv smbd[1108]: [2018/07/06 17:19:41.581914,  0] ../source3/smbd/server.c:1815(main)
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv smbd[1108]:   server role = 'active directory domain controller' not compatible with running smbd standalone.
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv smbd[1108]:   You should start 'samba' instead, and it will control starting smbd if required
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv systemd[1]: smbd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 06 17:19:41 exampleserv systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon.
```

Comment: You can start by doing what the error messages suggest: run `systemctl status nmbd.service`, `systemctl status winbind.service` and `systemctl status winbind.service`(evntualle with `sudo` in front if needed) .. and if you need more help, update tour question with the output from the commands.

Comment: I edited my question with the output for those commands.  Thanks